# Merge counts from 2 tables and group by date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables in SQL 2012, one containing incidents and one containing requests
I would like to be able to count the number of incidents and requests and group them by day but seem to be unable to work out how to do this.

Example Data is as follows

```
Incidents
ID     Created Date
IR1    01/02/16
IR2    01/02/16
IR3    02/02/16

Requests
ID    Created Date
SR4   01/02/16
SR5   02/02/16
SR6   03/02/16
```

I would Like to See

```
Incidents    Requests    Date
2            1           01/02/16
1            1           02/02/16
0            1           03/02/16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge them using UNION then you can group by and count:

```
SELECT [Created Date], SUM(i) Incidents, SUM(r) Requests
FROM (
  SELECT [Created Date], 1 i, 0 r FROM Incidents
  UNION
  SELECT [Created Date], 0, 1 FROM Requests
) tbl
GROUP BY [Created Date]
```